# Eclipse-generated JAD file does not automatically install dependent library

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am building a very simple BlackBerry app that consists of two projects, an Application and a Library.  I packaged both projects in Eclipse and uploaded the .cod files and the application's .jad file to our server.  When I try to install the app by downloading the .jad file, I get this error message:

`This application requires the following module, which is not installed: [name of Library module]`

How can I make eclipse generate a .jad file that properly installs dependent modules?

Answer (score 2):

You can merge two .JAD files by hand or you can use UpdateJad tool:

`updatejad.exe mainapp.jad libraryapp.jad`

(more information: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Install-two-cod-files-using-one-jad-file-OTA/m-p/482557#M97136)